# Trying to understand multiprocessing queues

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm still learning concurrency and multithreading in Python, and while I have lots of resources to dig into, I need to quickly find out the answer to a specific question.

I understand how, with `multiprocessing`, you can run multiple instances of a function over a collection of data with a piece of code like this:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

with Pool() as pool:
    pool.map(my_func, data)
```

Now, what if I have two functions, the first one whose output is the input to the second one, so that they can run in parallel? I understand the idea is to use a [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue), but all examples I found aren't that quick and easy to grasp. I went through section 10.4.10 of "The Python 3 Standard Library by Example", but couldn't see how to apply this to my case.

My use case is a program which copies files to a target folder, then computes the MD5 checksum of the copy. What I would like is for the copy of the next file to start while the MD5 checksum of the previously completed copy is computed. So the ouput of a function (copy) is a file name with path (string) which is the input of a second function (MD5 checksum).

Would someone have a basic model of code such as the one above to get me started?

Comment: why don't you compute the checksum while copying?  copying the file necessarily involves reading the file, so why not just pass it through the checksum at the same time.  when I tried to do something similar I thought it would be more important to overlap directory scanning with file handling.  I presume it would depend on how much of the directory tree you want to process/copy

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing your implementation but this is not fully a task for `Pool`.  The first question is what will your main program be doing.

One possibility is to have the main program do copying and have a pool of workers do the checksum calculation. Your main program copies files and you will then send the checksum calculation to workers. In this case you should use `pool.apply_async()` as `apply` is a blocking call.

Another possibility is to do both tasks in the same function inside the pool. If you have extra resources, just increase your number of workers. Both of your tasks are IO intensive. The bottleneck of this will be in IO and you will not benefit anything from adding more CPU to the task.  This is my favourite based on what little I know.

If you really need two subprocesses to do this - one to copy and one to count checksums, you will need a pool, a subprocess and a queue. Or just two subprocesses if the pool is not needed.  I am too lazy to write a working example but the idea is to create a `multiprocessing.queue()`, then use `multiprocessing.Process` to launch the checksum calculator with the queue as a parameter. Finally you will launch a pool - or another Process if one is enough to saturate your IO - and pass the same queue to the worker.

If you end up using Pool and decide to use map or map_async, you will also need to use `partial` from functools to create a copy of your worker that already has the queue as a parameter, as map is only able to send one parameter - the file name. If you use apply_async, then you can send both filename and queue to the worker as parameters.

When your copier has copied the file, it will `put()` the filename to the queue. Your checksum process is a while true loop that sits in `queue.get()` and waits for filenames to appear. If you then need to return the checksum somewhere, you will need another queue for outbound traffic, another parameter to subprocesses and the main program waiting to read results from this queue.

This works but I am fairly sure this will not improve performance compared to the model where your worker does copying and checksum calculation in one go. As you can see, it becomes much more convoluted and you will potentially lose some speed to sending information in queues back and forth. Queues work but they are not miracle performers.

Comment: My most sincere thanks for your detailed explanation. This really got me a long we to understanding the process. Based on this, I'm indeed less sure it's worth looking into for this use case. I may spend more time finding an optimal approach than would actually be gained from the performance increase, if it turns out to be marginal. Regardless of whether I have a solution to my question, I really gained a lot in understanding!